# Как деструктурировать дерево объектов, чтобы достать значение, находящееся в его глубине

Tags: javascript

Есть дерево обьектов:

```
const obj = {
 prop: [{insideProp : value}],
}
```

Как с помощью деструктурирующего присваивания взять `value`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Просто воссоздайте структуру слева и на месте нужного значения поставьте переменную:

```js
let { prop: [{ insideProp: variableForValue }] } =
    { prop: [{ insideProp: 'value'          }] };

console.log(variableForValue);
```